# login page for beginner

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, webforms

I know that it's a basic question about learning ASP.NET, I had searched on Google, StackOverflow, MSDN and CodeProject but nothing was found for my result.

I'm using ASP.NET (C#) to design a page `default.aspx` within 2 textboxes and a button (username, password and submit).

After login successfull, `Response.Redirect("userprofile.aspx");` will redirect me to the page.

Here is my question: On the page `userprofile.aspx`, if I click a link to move to `default.aspx`, "How to change 2 textboxes and a button (disable or disappear on page `default.aspx`) by 2 link `"Hi, username"` and `"Logout"`?

Thank you!

Comment: If an user is already logged in then you could redirect him back to userprofile.aspx when default.aspx is clicked

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Laszlo has provided your answer very well. That is the simpler as possible. If you are using VS 2012, create a template project with webforms and see the code there. There is an example.

Answer (score 1):

There's a control for that called LoginView with anonymous and logged-in template:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Display the username in the LoggedInTemplate and the textboxes and the button in the AnonymousTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my bad English. To do what you ask, there are various ways. You could, for example, enter the value **"Username"** within the `ViewState["USERNAME"]` and then once returned to the Default page, if any value in `ViewState["USERNAME"]`, to appear a `<div>` with `"Hi , "+ Viewstate["USERNAME"]"` with the button next to logoff.
I repeat, this is just one of many ways that you can take, and for sure there are better ones such as the use of a Master.Page.

Comment: for master.page read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The easy way that i proposed to you is this:

```
1- define session in global file :  Session["user_name"] = "";
2- if login successfully : Session["user_name"] = texUsername.Text;
2- check it in form load : 

if(Session["user_name"] == "")
   // ... visiable login panel  &  change wellcome text
else
   // ... invisiable login panel  &  change wellcome text to username
```